# Create Dynamic class in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

```
String name = "register";
Class<?> classObj = Class.forName(name);
stateComponent = (IState) classObj.newInstance();
```

This is my code creating a dynamic class in java. Can anyone give me a start how to make a dynamic class in c#?

Comment: Read about reflection in MSDN.

Comment: First result on Google for *Create Dynamic class in c#*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#'s class that corresponds to Java's `Class<T>` is `System.Type`. Unlike Java, `Type` is not generic (it does not need to be, because .NET does not use type erasure to implement generics).

Your Java code translates as follows:

```
string name = "..."; // Full name of your class
Type typeObj = Type.GetType(name);
// Get the default constructor
ConstructorInfo constr = typeObj.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
// Invoke the constructor to create the object
stateComponent = (IState)constr.Invoke(new object[0]);
```

Comment: why i'm getting null in this line of code Type typeObj=Type.GetType(name);  I pass a string name typeof(DownloadNewsState).Name;

Comment: @CarloAdap You need to pass the namespace-qualified name of the class. In addition, the assembly with the class needs to be linked with your application in order for this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Here your type name"));
```